# stat() not working for large filenames

Tags: c, stat

I'm trying to write a program which reads a filename input from the user, stores it in 'name' and then later on will check if the filename entered is in the current directory. The problem I'm having is that when the user enters a filename of a file which doesnt exist in the directory, then one which does with a name longer than the previous it works, but if the user enteers first a long nonexistant filename then a shorter one which does exist

```
stat(name, &check)<0
```

and doesn't fine it.
I'm wondering if because 'name' in the second instance is an array with the correct filename but then '\0's to fill it to the size of the previous larger wrong attempt entered has something to do with it comparing the filenames. Is there any way I could either clear 'name' each attempt without using fflush?

```
char *filename(int *valid_input)
{

    /* Need to malloc name, dat and prefix if doing it this way. */
    int valid1, valid2, valid3, i, n;
    char c, *name;
    char dat[5], prefix[16];
    struct stat check;

    name = malloc(14*(sizeof(char)));

    if(name==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory could not be allocated.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter a filename in the form 'yourfile.dat'.\nUse only lowercase letters a-z and numerals 0-9 in the prefix. \n The prefix should be 10 characters or less.\nIf you wish to quit enter 'q'.\n\nInput filename : ");

    *valid_input = 0;

    while(*valid_input == 0)
    {
        valid1=0; valid2=0; valid3=0;

         __fpurge(stdin);
        printf("hello1");

        while(valid1==0)  /* Checks input is at least 5 characters long, 14 maximum. */
        {
           printf("hello2");
            n = 0;
            valid1 = 1;

            __fpurge(stdin);

            while ((c=(char)getchar()) != '\n') /* Reads in input */
               {
                   printf("hello3");
                   if(n<14)
                   {
                       name[n]=c;
                       /*printf("%c",name[n]); */
                       if((name[n]=='\n')||(name[n]==EOF)||(name[n]=='\0')) break;
                   }
                   ++n;
               }

           /* printf("check"); */
            if(((n>=14)&&(name[14]!='t'))||(n<5)){printf("hello1");  valid1 = 0;} /* Checks input has a prefix and is less than                     14 characters total */

            if((name[0]=='q')&&(n==1)){printf("hello"); break;}

            if(valid1 > 0) break;

          /* printf("Length of name = %d n = %d ",strlen(name),n);*/
            printf("\nYour filename should contain a prefix of up to 10 characters. \nTo quit press 'q'.\n\nInput filename : ");
        }

        if((name[0]=='q')&&(n==1)) break;

        for (i=0;i<(n-4);i++)
        {

            prefix[i]=name[i];
            printf("\nprefixvalue = %c",prefix[i]);
            if(((prefix[i]>='a')&&(prefix[i]<='z'))||((prefix[i]>='0')&&(prefix[i]<='9'))){ valid3+=1;}
        }
        if(valid3!=n-4) valid3=0;
        else valid3=1;

        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            dat[i]=name[n-4+i];
            if((dat[0]='.')||(dat[1]='d')||(dat[2]='a')||(dat[3]='t')) valid2=1;
        }

        if((valid2==0)||(valid3==0)) printf("\nYour filename should be in the form 'yourfile.dat' with only lowercase letters or numbers in the prefix.\nTo quit press q.\n\nInput filename : ");

        *valid_input = valid1 && valid2 && valid3;

        if(*valid_input==1)
        {
            if(stat(name, &check)<0)
               {
                printf("\n File does not exist in the current directory.\n Check and re-enter filename.\n To quit press q.\n\nfilename : "); *valid_input=0;
               }
        }

    }

    return(name);
```

Comment: For which operating system is this? MS-DOS? Unix 7?

Answer (score 5):

The big problem you have is that you don't terminate the string `name`.

To start with, you should allocate one more character for the terminator:

```
name = malloc(15);  /* C specifies that `sizeof(char)` is always 1 */
```

Then after the `getchar` loop, you should terminate the string:

```
name[n] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the bug found by Joachim, there is another:

```
if(((n>=14)&&(name[14]!='t'))||(n<5)){printf("hello1");  valid1 = 0;}
```

I don't have any idea why `name[14]!='t'` has special significance, but in any case, `n` is the number of characters read so far, so if `n == 14` then `name[14]`, which is the *fifteenth* character, will be as yet unassigned and this test will behave unpredictably.